# Alphabets not identified in Slot

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I add slot  with Slot values A,B,C,D,E & F.  Using "Evaluate Model" when I am testing it's not identifying B,C,D,E & F.

I am building a Quiz model.  When I try to add I slot  with Slot values A,B,C,D,E & F.  Using "Evaluate Model" when I am testing it's not identifying B,C,D,E & F.

Comment: are u adding the slot values individually or a comma separated list

Comment: @Juned Ahsan ..  Individually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a dot after the character in the slot (and in the Evaluate Model)

If you say to Alexa "a" in the request will arrive "a." so i think it can be your issue.

(eventually you can put the character without the dot in the ID)

Comment: -   (eventually you can put the character without the dot in the ID)  -  Please elaborate

Comment: @bgara when you define a Slot Type, you have to provide a mandatory value. You can also provide an optional ID that (in your lambda or your backend) you can retrieve. So try putting the character with the dot ("a.", "b." and so on) in the value and without the dot in the ID. It's only for your convenience, it doesn't change anything (ID is optional). It is useful if you have some synonyms for example, in order to have a common value (the ID) for every synonym.

Comment: Thank you its working except for letter 'E'   tried e.  E.

Comment: @bgara all letters work except E? That's strange... But in the evaluate model or with the real device?

Answer (score 0):

This works if you are setting the slot values individually and not as a single comma separated list. Here is I configured and tested it

Slot config

[image]

Test result

[image]

Comment: My utterance looks similar. Yes, two words (like Option {Alphabet}, input alphabet {Alphabet}) in the utterance are working fine.  can you just put {Alphabet} and try